# How to find LUA method for VIM Command

Tags: vimscript, neovim, vimscript-lua, init

I am in the process of converting my .vimrc to init.lua. Several of my lines end up containing vimscript inside a call to `vim.cmd`, such as

```
vim.cmd("highlight Normal guibg=none ctermbg=none")
vim.cmd("highlight EndOfBuffer guibg=none ctermbg=none")
vim.cmd("highlight cursorline cterm=none ctermbg=236")
vim.cmd("highlight cursorcolumn cterm=none ctermbg=236")

vim.cmd("syntax on")
vim.cmd("filetype on")
```

How can I find the corresponding lua functions to call for these features?

Comment: Probably in the `:help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `highlight` command, you can use function `nvim_set_hl()` instead:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Normal', {fg = '#00ffff', bg = '#ff0000'})
```

There is not equivalent function for `syntax on` and `filetype on` in lua.